# CakePHP: Adding days to a Date field and compare them in find query

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, cakephp-2.4

I have a Model in my database, which has a Datetime field. I have to write a find query in CakePHP like `$this->Model->find('.....`, where I add a number of days to this Datetime and then I compare to today's date. Something like `Model.date + numOfDays == today`. How can I implement this ?

Answer (score 0):

**As per logic**

```
Model.date + numOfDays == today
```

The above condition equals the following

```
Model.date  == today - numOfDays
```

So try the following:

```
$numOfDays = -1 * $numOfDays;
$compare_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($numOfDays +' days'));
```

CakePHP Condition is:

```
Model.date == $compare_date
```

Comment: I know this fitch with strtotime, but how do I add and subtract the fields of the Model. I don't have them as variables